# How would multiprocessing work for a program under a single method

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

In my case the entire program falls under a single method. How do I apply multiprocessing here as the execution of this program takes a lot of time?

My For loop is processing the files with more than 1 million of data and there is a lot of comparisons that goes through. 
I'm not sure how this works. I tried some example from stack itself but no luck.

My Code:

```
def MSP():
#print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

xlsx = ExcelFile('XX.xlsx')
df = xlsx.parse(xlsx.sheet_names[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['XX'])
#Second File [Raw Data]
print()
Ofilename = input('Enter a filename: ')
dg = pd.read_csv(Ofilename, usecols = ['XX','XXX','XXXX'], encoding="ISO-8859-1") #

# DataFrame to List
pla = dg['XX'].values.tolist()
nam = dg['XXX'].values.tolist()
cat = dg['XXXX'].values.tolist()
bat= df2['XX'].values.tolist()

dfu= df2.values.tolist()            
dgu= dg.values.tolist()             

caughtw = len(bat)
totalw = len(dgu)
totalj = totalw + 1

bl=[]
i = 0
j = 0
z = 0
e = []

header_addedone = False
header_addedtwo = False

print()
print("Job started, processing data...")

# dru = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols = ['XX','XXX','XXXX'], encoding="ISO-8859-1")
# plar = dru['XX'].values.tolist()
# namr = dru['XXX'].values.tolist()
# catr = dru['XXXX'].values.tolist()

for i in range(caughtw):
    d = bat[i]          

    for j in range(totalw):
        c = nam[j]          
        e = str(c)
        f = pla[j]          
        substring = str(d)
        search = re.search('\\b'+substring+'\\b',e, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

        if search:
            match = search.group()
            index = search.start()
            #print("matched", match, "at index", index)
            bl=dgu[j]
            #print(bl)

            filename="Output/XX words.csv"
            # field names
            with open(filename, 'a', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as csvfile: #utf-8
                # # creating a csv writer object
                csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

                if not header_addedone:
                    csvwriter.writerow(['XX','XXX','XXXX'])
                    header_addedone = True

                # writing the data rows
                csvwriter.writerow(bl)
                z+=1
                # writing the fields


print("The total words XX is",z)


if __name__ == '__main__':

#use one less process to be a little more stable
# p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
# #timing it...
# start = time.time()
# # for file in names:
# p.apply_async(Mispelledw, [file])
#
# p.close()
# p.join()
# print("Complete")
# end = time.time()
# print('total time (s)= ' + str(end-start))
# 
# p = Pool(processes = len(totalw))
# start = time.time()
# async_result = p.map_async(Mispelledw, names)
# p.close()
# p.join()
# print("Complete")
# end = time.time()
# print('total time (s)= ' + str(end-start))

make_sure_path_exists(path)
MSP()

# result = p.map(Mispelledw)
# p.close()
# p.join()
#
# print("Pool took : ",time.time()-t1)
```

Comment: Kindly clarify for me: Do you want a suggestion where to best multithread in your algorithm or a suggestion for multithreading code?

Comment: I want to implement multiprocessing in my code above, but the examples available around is not clear and related to my case where only a single function exists. How can I apply it to a program with a single function?

Comment: Well in order to apply multithreading to a single function you have to at least split the code into 2(/multiple) different functional units which can be performed on 2(/multiple) threads. If this is done in a single function or in multiple is irrelevant, as you definitely have to create 2(/multpile) functional units. In a way - at I least that's how I grasp your understanding of the problem - you have to create multiple *functions* either way.

Comment: I do agree with Pual here but as u can see my case is a kind of nested condition where a output of first loop goes as an input for second. I not sure how I can divide this one. Is there a way around here.